# Allowing only one of three buttons to submit a web form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

If i have something like:

```
<form method="post" id="customForm" action="">
    //stuff 

    <div id="copiar">
        <button class="button" href="#" id="btnAdd0">
            <span class="icon icon3">&nbsp;</span>
        </button>
        <button class="button" href="#" id="btnDel0">
            <span class="icon icon58">&nbsp;</span>
        </button>
        <button class="submeter">
            <span class="label">Send</span>
        </button>
    </div>  
    </form>
```

and:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#customForm").submit(function() {
            var formdata = $("#customForm").serializeArray();
            $.ajax({
                url: "validation.php",
                type: "post",
                dataType: "json",
                data: formdata,
                success: function(data, data1) {
                   //stuff
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

At the moment, the three buttons send the form. My idea is only permit the submit action in this button:

```
<button class="submeter">
    <span class="label">Send</span>
</button>
```

I already tried  `$("#customForm > #copiar > button.submeter").submit(function() {`
but the page is  reloaded. So isn't working.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to stop the other buttons from submitting first and then do your submit.  Also when using an ID for your selector there really isn't any need to combine it with another ID like #customForm > #copiar "

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#customForm").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formdata = $("#customForm").serializeArray();
        $.ajax({
            url: "validation.php",
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            data: formdata,
            success: function(data, data1) {
               //stuff
            }
        });
    });
    $("#customForm button").click(function(e) {
        var me = $(this);
        e.preventDefault();

        if(me.hasClass("submeter")) $("#customForm").submit();
    });
});
```

And as has already been pointed out, you don't need/want the href="#"

Answer (score 1):

In order to prevent the default behavior of the form, you must use `preventDefault()` as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#customForm").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formdata = $("#customForm").serializeArray();
        $.ajax({
            url: "validation.php",
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            data: formdata,
            success: function(data, data1) {
               //stuff
        });
    });
    $("#customForm button.submeter").click(function() {
        $("#customForm").submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: I think you still want another preventDefault inside of the click binding for the buttons and you need to check if the button clicked is the correct button.

Answer (score 1):

What is exactly the purpose of first two button element with the `href` attribute? I suspect you're using a button instead of a regular link only for a formatting/visual reason.

Anyway for your purpose, just add the attribute type="submit" to the last button and remove the submit handler you've defined for this button, it should work fine.

edit. you also need to call the preventDefault() method to stop page reload, as pointed out by phil klein

Comment: not sure this really answers the OP question.  Maybe I'm missing something though.  Perhaps you could post code for your proposed solution?